# What are the thresholds for not being notified of an edit?

Tags: support, edits, notifications

According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/213575, there are two thresholds for not being notified of edits:

> - the edit in the post body should be over a threshold
> - the edit in code sections should be over another threshold

What are these thresholds? Which are the events in which edits are (not) notified?

Comment: I assume they are the same thresholds that could put a question into the re-open queue and to prevent gaming those are kept secret. But we'll see if I'm wrong this time ...

Comment: It seems that entire discussion in limited to real-time notifications ([based on this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post/202415#comment866016_202415)). I think you are always notified of those edits in [your profile > responses > revised tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=responses&sort=revisions).

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what necessity there is to not always notify of every edit. Even very tiny small edits of 1 character may have a negative impact sometimes, so you need to be aware of all the edits on your posts.

Comment: @Cœur As mentioned in the comment I've linked, it requires web sockets to push those notifications to the browser in real time. Keeping a threshold on the number of characters would let them drastically reduce the number of real time notifications. Hence the load on their servers would also reduce. Which in turn, lets them utilize that *additional capacity* for other - more important - purposes. But I don't think it is implied anywhere that such edits are hidden from the user. Hence I'd assume the notifications would still appear in the responses > revised tab **when you visit your profile**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact threshold is:

- at least 10 characters (this is using a diff algorithm, so it's not a simple add/delete; and is naturally a little fuzzy); or
- changes to code of at least 2 characters

[What type of notifications do we have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134906/what-type-of-notifications-do-we-have/135411#comment378020_135411)

If you want these thresholds to be changed, submit a meta question. Remember, these apply only for those users that have over 2k reputation. **You are always notified of suggested edits.**