# When is it "bad" to answer an old question?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

Before going into details, I'd like to mention that I consider any post older than 60 days to be an old post.

Recently (more accurately, last month), I have gotten into the habit of picking up some older questions in the [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) and improving them by either

1. Voting on the question and/or answers
2. Editing answers to improve relevancy (if the edits are minor)
3. Flagging, deleting plagiarised content, and
4. If it really deserves it, answering the question myself.

Or all of the above. I usually only answer the question when I *know* I have something substantial to contribute over the existing answers, such as in situations where the existing answers are inaccurate, incomplete, or out-of date.

Recently, a user pointed out on two separate occasions that my actions on older questions was not useful to the community. I will not link that user directly, but these are their comments, posted under two separate answers that I found unsettling:

> It's particularly problematic because the details of which methods are
>   good for which cases often change, and so having very lengthy, deep
>   dive answers on SO is not only not as useful as having it in the
>   pandas official documentation, but often is even harmful or misleading
>   because some change to the function internals can suddenly make the
>   answer incorrect or factually wrong and it's not clearly linked to the
>   actual source repo to flag for documentation updating.

This comment from the user criticises "deep-dive" posts (the kind of posts I enjoy writing, especially to older questions), but I understand where they are coming from, so, fine. However, this comment from them on another answer of mine was a little different:

> This seems more appropriate as a set of suggested updates to the
>   accepted answer. In general I've seen a number of answers from you
>   that follow that pattern.. it probably would help the community more
>   rather than fracturing where the info is located on the page by
>   splitting current-version "update" answers into standalone answers
>   elsewhere on the page (just a suggestion).

I understand there is a lack of context because I have not linked to the post. But, under this particular question, the currently accepted answer to this particular question was somewhat terse, and one of the options used a deprecated method. In my answer, I referenced the accepted answer *in juxtaposition* to my suggested approaches. I explained that the current answer was deprecated, and how the updated answer would be for today's version of pandas.

However, this user's argument is that I should refrain from posting completely, and just stick to editing other existing answers, especially for "update" answers which signal that the existing answers are deprecated. Now, my arguments against this are

1. I would understand if the question had a collaborative-lock. But these questions are open, meaning contributions in answer form are *welcome*.
2. Neither the question, nor the answers are community wiki'd.
3. There exists [the Necromancer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) that encourages knowledge sharing on older posts.

There are also well reputed users such as [@AaronHall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541136/aaron-hall) and [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-%E6%96%B0%E7%96%86%E6%94%B9%E9%80%A0%E4%B8%AD%E5%BF%83-%E5%85%AD%E5%9B%9B%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6-%E6%B3%95%E8%BD%AE%E5%8A%9F) who make a living out of answering old questions.

So, to summarise... in light of the pushback I've received, I thought it would be good to take a step back and figure out when older questions deserve an answer. More specifically, if an answer is outdated, must it always be required that you update the answer yourself, instead of posting your own answer, even if the edit is not trivial?

Comment: Actually, of the last 20 questions I've answered now, 15 of them are oldies. If you would like to evaluate the content/relevance of my answers, please feel free to do so if that helps you provide a more accurate response to this question. Please, however, do not engage in serial up/down voting.

Comment: I really don't buy that user's comments (I responded as such on that post). Just because SO answers are not linked directly to the pandas repository, is *not* a reason not to post here. This isn't the official documentation, anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a comment telling someone not to answer constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348633/is-a-comment-telling-someone-not-to-answer-constructive)

Comment: I think the fact that I am asking about old questions, and more specifically whether the arguments by this user are justified or not, make this not duplicate of that. Just reading that question would not have been enough to convince me otherwise.

Comment: As long as your answers are good, I think it isn't constructive for the user to tell you not to answer.

Comment: If, per comment, it's true that the optimal methods to use change based on version, then it sounds like you could just mention the version(s) for which your answer is aimed at.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Linking full comments kind of gives away where it came from, this is a tech community after all.

As a result of full context being included to some degree, I think it is fair to say that what you are experiencing is a niche problem that has something to do with factors outside of Stack Overflow.

**It is never bad to answer an old question solely because the question was asked some time ago.**

My advice would be to keep doing what you are doing, the content you provide is very high quality. It is very rare to come across a problem and think "wow, I wish that the solution hadn't covered all the bases like that".

The decision to edit an answer versus posting a different one should be rather straightforward. If you are going to be adding in a whole section of new content, that should be a new answer; especially if code or diagrams are involved. If you are merely tidying up the answer, that should be an edit. If there is a technical inaccuracy with the answer, then downvote and/or request clarification on the inaccuracy (do be careful with commenting about downvoting though, it can cause friction).

With regards to the external factors, I think that should be flattering, not dissuasive. Clearly there is a frustration with the documentation situation that comes through, but you shouldn't take that personally.

Answer (score 50):

If the question:

- Is not closed
- Should not be closed

and the answer will provide value (e.g. won't repeat what other answers already say), it's fine to post an answer no matter how old the question is.

I imagine that if a question were *protected*, or already had **a lot** of answers, it might be better to think a bit harder if a new answer would really be needed or good.

But since the answer box doesn't automatically closes as the question gets older, **question age** should not be a consideration when answering. 
**Answer usefulness** should be.

It's exactly the same criteria to be applied to new questions: You think that the question is on-topic and clear, you know how to answer it and want to answer it, and you believe the the answer would provide value for future visitors.

Comment: Is it really this simple? What of this particular user's arguments with respect to editing existing answers instead of writing a new one? Which would be more useful to do?

Comment: I believe it is this simple. Additional considerations about "when to edit" are too circumstance dependant, you need to look at each case in isolation. But basically, whenever the edits do not change the original answer too much (the old answer could be useful for some users), edits are good. Generally, I prefer new answers to updated answers. Old technology does not disappear.

Comment: I understand, I did not want to do that because it would mean drawing attention to the question, answer, and user which I've learned is counter-productive to a healthy discussion. Although you could probably find out just by looking at my comment history.

Comment: I think it would be good to point out if it would be good to add as a new answer to a new question it should also be good to add as a new answer to an older one.

Comment: @coldspeed Since your question does not want to center on a specific q&a, I rather answer the general case. So no need to crawl your profile. :)

Comment: As long as one is providing answer, and good one by the way. no matter how old the question is. If you have fun and provide valuable answer the only thing I can say is: Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You are curating high-quality content for a popular API. You don't need to justify your canonical-style answers. On SO, one-liners *and* in-depth answers alike are appreciated.

And yet...

> it probably would help the community more rather than fracturing where
>   the info is located on the page by splitting current-version "update"
>   answers into standalone answers elsewhere on the page (just a
>   suggestion).

The guy **has a point**. It's why I raised this Meta: [What to do with existing answers when a method is renamed in an API?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376474/what-to-do-with-existing-answers-when-a-method-is-renamed-in-an-api) The [consensus answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376532/9209546) was to go ahead and update an answer to reflect a renamed method where syntax is identical. This happens a lot with APIs as they develop and mature.

So I went ahead and [made such an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12133235/revisions) on an old Q&A you recently answered. It's not a "one or the other" scenario, you can update the one-liner in an outdated answer **and** write your in-depth canonical. *Many* won't read your in-depth answer and your edit will have just as much impact as your canonical. *Some* surely will appreciate the nuances and explanation in your answer, and you'll be rewarded over time for your contribution.

Comment: As you said, I don't think there is a single correct answer here. From the meta post you linked, the post was closed as a dupe of [another one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265434/4909087) where the consensus was to write a new answer. Perhaps we can do both. I, personally, am handling it on a case-by-case basis. If the update is trivial enough, an edit is fine. If more details are worth fleshing out, write an answer.

Comment: @coldspeed, Sure, this was my major gripe with my Meta being closed as a duplicate (sadly, didn't get traction on [my comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376474/what-to-do-with-existing-answers-when-a-method-is-renamed-in-an-api#comment646917_376474)). I think the point still stands that this isn't a "one or the other" scenario. *Especially* if there's an accepted one-line answer, a renamed method probably *should* be added as an edit, assuming identical syntax. This shouldn't stop your writing, as you've already done, the canonical.

Comment: Here I am, commenting on an old question.  :)  I think the "edit the answer" idea is fine, but I would perhaps do it by leaving the old version of the code in place, commented out with an appropriate comment as to why.  `// This call was deprecated in version 2.1, and replaced by the new function below.`